# c# circular generic type parameters

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, circular-dependency

I have 2 generic classes: a ManagerBase class and a ChildBase class.
They're both abstract and are intended to be made concrete.
ManagerBase has a list of ChildBase, which is why I want to make it generic, so a CatalogManager : ManagerBase would have a list of Catalogs. Also, each Catalog would have reference to its' Manager - CatalogManager.

```
public class ManagerBase<T1> : ChildBase<???>
{
    public ManagerBase()
    {
        ChildObjects = new List<T1>();
    }

    public List<T1> ChildObjects { get; set; }
}

public class ChildBase<T1> : ManagerBase<???>
{
    public ChildBase(T1 parentMgr)
    {
        ParentMgr = parentMgr;
        ParentMgr.ChildObjects.Add(this);
    }

    public T1 ParentMgr { get; set; }
}
```

How can I resolve this object model?

Thanks.

Comment: `public class ManagerBase<TManager, TChild> where TManager : ManagerBase<TManager, TChild> where TChild : ChildBase<TManager, TChild>`, `public class ChildBase<TManager, TChild> where TManager : ManagerBase<TManager, TChild> where TChild : ChildBase<TManager, TChild>`, `class CatalogManager : ManagerBase<CatalogManager, Catalog>`, `class Catalog : ChildBase<CatalogManager, Catalog>`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the base classes using the "curiously recursive" pattern:

```
public class ManagerBase<M, T1>
    where M : ManagerBase<M, T1>
    where T1 : ChildBase<M, T1>
{
    public ManagerBase()
    {
        ChildObjects = new List<T1>();
    }

    public List<T1> ChildObjects { get; set; }
}

public class ChildBase<T1, C>
    where T1 : ManagerBase<T1, C>
    where C : ChildBase<T1, C>
{
    public ChildBase(T1 parentMgr)
    {
        ParentMgr = parentMgr;
        ParentMgr.ChildObjects.Add((C)(object)this);
    }

    public T1 ParentMgr { get; set; }
}
```

Please note I've stuck with your usage of `T1`, but I think that's a bit confusing. I would have preferred to have used `M` and `C` for each.

The major downside with this is that you have to use the nasty double cast of `(C)(object)this` to make this work. C# doesn't allow full type safety on this pattern. A nefarious developer can create child classes that can break the pattern.

Then the concrete classes can be this:

```
public class CatalogManager : ManagerBase<CatalogManager, Catalog>
{
}

public class Catalog : ChildBase<CatalogManager, Catalog>
{
    public Catalog(CatalogManager parentMgr) : base(parentMgr)
    {
    }
}
```